# How to flip bits in C#?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a binary number in the form of a string as

```
string input = "10110101101";
```

Now I need to flip (`0 to 1` and `1 to 0`) the *first 3 bits* of it.

The resultant output will be **010**10101101

How to do so in C#?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you even looked?  This is exactly the kind of question you could have answered by typing less words into google than you typed here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way using `Convert.ToInt32`, `Convert.ToString` (which otherwise unknown and unused), and `bitwise-XOR`

```
string input = "10110101101";
int flipNo = 3;
int output = Convert.ToInt32(input, 2);
for (int i = input.Length - 1; i >= input.Length - flipNo; --i)
    output ^= 1 << i;
```

Simply use the `output`, or if you want to display the `output` in `string`, you could do:

```
string display = Convert.ToString(output, 2).PadLeft(input.Length, '0');
```

Comment: Sir, I liked your logic but the output of ur program is 01000101101 where as it should be 01010101101

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar ah, yes. The flip is one too many, thanks for pointing it out. Simply change `-1-flipNo` in the `for loop` to `-flipNo`

Answer (score 8):

This works:

```
string input = "10110101101";

string output =
    new string(
        input
            .Take(3)
            .Select(c => c == '0' ? '1' : '0')
            .Concat(input.Skip(3))
            .ToArray());
```

It gives the result:

```
01010101101
```

Another alternative is to do this:

```
string input = "10110101101";
string flips = "11100000000";

int value = Convert.ToInt32(input, 2) ^ Convert.ToInt32(flips, 2);

string output = Convert.ToString(value, 2).PadLeft(input.Length, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

Make `StringBuilder` out of your string, flip the initial three characters, and convert `StringBuilder` back to `string`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(input);
Debug.Assert(sb.Length >= 3);
for (int i = 0 ; i != 3 ; i++) {
    sb[i] = sb[i] == '0' ? '1' : '0';
}
var res = sb.ToString();
```

There are various "smart" ways of flipping the characters without conditional, but given that the number is in a `string` making the flip smarter wouldn't buy you much CPU cycles.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/wky46n)

Comment: I like the idea - IMO the most clean from all posted +1. There is a small bug though - the `for` condition should be `i < 3`. Also no real benefit of using `StringBuilder` - `ToCharArray()` to get `char[]`, same loop, then `new string(char[])`?

Comment: @IvanStoev `i != 3` is not a bug, it is intentional. Good point about using arrays. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are given an array a of size `N`. The elements of the array are  `a[0], a[1], ... a[N - 1]`, where each a is either `0` or `1`. You can perform one transformation on the array: choose any two integers `L`, and `R`, and flip all the elements between (and including) the Lth and Rth bits. In other words, L and R represent the left-most and the right-most index demarcating the boundaries of the segment whose bits you will decided to flip. ('Flipping' a bit means, that a `0` is transformed to a `1` and a  `1` is transformed to a  `0`.)
What is the maximum number of '1'-bits (indicated by S) which you can obtain in the final bit-string?
Input Format:
The first line has a single integerN
The next `N` lines contains the `N` elements in the array, `a[0], a[1], ... a[N - 1]`, one per line.

For instance consider

```
1 ≤ N ≤ 100,000. 

d can be either 0 or 1. It cannot be any other integer.
0 ≤ L ≤ R < N
Sample Input:
810010010
Sample Output:
6
Explanation:
We can get a maximum of 6 ones in the given binary array by performing either of the following operations:
Flip [1, 5] ⇒ 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
or 
Flip [1, 7] ⇒ 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

**Solution:**
The bits array will only contain 0 and 1. So we can view 0 as -1, then the task is to find the 
minimum sum of subArray in bits, which is the subArray that has the largest value of
(number of 0s- number of 1s). 
We can use the same method as find maximum sum subArray to find minimum sum subArray. Before that,
we need to traverse bits first to get original number of 1s. Suppose the minimum sum is minRes and
original number of 1s is currentOne. Then minRes should be a negative number, so return currentOne-minRes.
Edge case:
All edge cases can be handled using the above method. If all elements are 0, then we add all -1 together.
If all elements are 1, then the minRes should be 0, which means we do not do flip any bit.
Time: O(n)  Space: O(1)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static int FlippingBits(int[] bits){
        int currentOne = 0; //original number of 1s in bits
        foreach(int i in bits){
            if(i==1)
                currentOne++;
        }
        int minRes = MinSubArray(bits); //minRes is negative number
        return currentOne-minRes;
    }

    //find the min sum of subArray in bits
    private static int MinSubArray(int[] bits){
        int minRes = 0, minHere=0;
        foreach(int i in bits){
            if(i==0)
                minHere-=1;
            else
                minHere+=1;
            minHere = Math.Min(minHere,0); //keep minHere<=0
            minRes = Math.Min(minHere, minRes);
        }
        return minRes; //-minRes is the number of 1 can be added to the array after flipping
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
            string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            int[] bits = input.Select(y=>int.Parse(y)).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(FlippingBits(bits));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution is quite simple; just XOR the values with 1 (0 works too).

Steps:

1. For the first x characters, XOR with 1 and get the return value (simple for loop).
2. Replace the old string with the new one.